# What does it mean when cops pull someone over?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

When someone says the cops pull someone over, what does it mean? Does it mean the person was running away from the cops and the cops moved the car in front of the driver's car and the driver had to stop the car on the side of the road?

I searched in the dictionary but the meaning is limited to stopping a car on the side of the road. But what does it mean **when cops pull someone over**?

Comment: They stop a car that is being driven in order to make enquiries.  It only refers to vehicles and their drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean the person was running away from the cops and the cops moved the car in front of the driver's car and the driver had to stop the car on the side of the road?

No, it simply means that the cops signaled to the driver (by using sirens) that he needed to pull over to the side of the road, and that the driver obeyed.